# Spotfire- Sorting stacked bar chart

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart for number of accounts we opened in spotfire; since there are a lot of values, I used the bin function for number and I am coloring by Names of Account-Holding agencies. Spotfire is stacking these colors by agencies high to low; I'd like to make is low to high such that the contributors of maximum accounts are the topmost color in the chart. Traditional sorting of bars is not working. Could someone please let me know if there is any alternative way I can sort by colors?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in the latest release, 7.5. We have not upgraded to 7.5 yet but stacked bar chart sorting is mentioned on page 5 of the [release notes](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.5.0/TIB_sfire-analyst_7.5.0_relnotes.pdf).